# Immutable vs Mutable C#

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to write a quick snippet to demonstrate the difference between an immutable and mutable type.
Does this code seem to right to you all?

```
class MutableTypeExample
{
    private string _test; //members are not readonly
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set { _test = value; } //class is mutable because it can be modified after being created
    }

    public MutableTypeExample(string test)
    {
        _test = test;
    }

    public void MakeTestFoo()
    {
        this.Test = "FOO!";
    }
}

class ImmutableTypeExample
{
    private readonly string _test; //all members are readonly
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; } //no set allowed
    }

    public ImmutableTypeExample(string test) //immutable means you can only set members in the consutrctor. Once the object is instantiated it cannot be altered
    {
        _test = test;
    }

    public ImmutableTypeExample MakeTestFoo()
    {
        //this.Test = "FOO!"; //not allowed because it is readonly
        return new ImmutableTypeExample("FOO!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not the class that is mutable but a field. You can mix up `readonly` and "normal" fields in a class as long as `readonly` fields are only assigned in the constructor code or at initialization time.

Comment: `ImmutableTypeExample MakeTestFoo()` doesn't make much sense. Is it supposed to be static?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup, that looks reasonable.

However, I would *also* talk about "leaky" mutability. For example:

```
public class AppearsImmutableButIsntDeeplyImmutable
{
    private readonly StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    public StringBuilder Builder { get { return builder; } }
}
```

I can't change *which* builder an instance appears on, but I can do:

```
value.Builder.Append("hello");
```

It would be worth you reading Eric Lippert's blog post on [kinds of immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) - and indeed all the rest of the posts in the series.

Comment: In other words, the example only works because the string property it uses also happens to be immutable. As soon as you have a mutable property, even if it only available via a getter, you aren't fully immutable.

Comment: You might also reason about collections, immutable/mutable class pairs etc. I wrote an article on that recently that should be interesting in this context: http://rickyhelgesson.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/mutable-or-immutable-in-a-parallel-world/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that looks right.

Note that the private members doesn't need to be readonly for the class to be immutable, that is just an extra precaution agains broken code inside the class.